# Animation blocks interfering with one another

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm basically running two animations, one after the other, and it seems that they are interfering with each other or the UIView somehow. My code works perfectly fine on the 5.0 Simulator, but is having issues in 4.3 Simulator.

Basically I have a bunch of images on the screen. When the object gets touched, it scales up in size:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^(void) {
                         //resizing the frame to make it bigger (original size is the new bigger size)
                         self.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - originalSize.width/2, point.y - originalSize.height/2 , originalSize.width, originalSize.height);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL complete){
                         //I have a showArrow method that draws an arrow to the superview to show the user where to place their image
                         [self performSelector:@selector(showArrow) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
                     }];
```

Once that block is complete, it runs showArrow, which just shows a bouncing arrow:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^(void) {
                         self.arrow.frame = CGRectMake(arrowOrigin.origin.x, arrowOrigin.origin.y - 200, arrow.frame.size.width, arrow.frame.size.height);
                         self.arrow.alpha = 0.5;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

So as I mentioned, this works perfectly on my iPad and the 5.0 simulator, but in 4.3, once the first animation runs, it seems to freeze the image's pan gestures or ability to be touched. Any ideas on whats up with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` mask to the options parameter

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn |
                            UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void) {
                 // ...
```

And in `showArrow`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |
                            UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
                            UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void) {
                 // ...
```